# Generate DDL with Hibernate 4 without connection

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, maven, ddl

I used to generate DDL using *hibernate3-maven-plugin* with Hibernate 3.
Since I switched to **Hibernate 4** I can't use this plugin anymore.

I can't find a way to generate a DDL from mapping without being connected to an actual **PostgreSQL** database.

I tried a lot of stuff (including *hibernate4-maven-plugin* from de.juplo and [this](https://techblog.bozho.net/how-to-generate-a-schema-creation-script-with-hibernate-4-jpa-and-maven/)) but I feel like each method requires a DB connection.

Is there a (good) way to generate DDL in Hibernate 4 without connection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can generate my DDL script in this way:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>de.juplo</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>export</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <hibernateDialect>org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</hibernateDialect>

                    <!-- I want generate the schemas for these dialects too, at same time... -->
                    <!-- <hibernateDialect>org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</hibernateDialect> -->
                    <!-- <hibernateDialect>org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</hibernateDialect> -->

                    <target>SCRIPT</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I do not need any connection, I just specify the SQL dialect. Using `mvn clean package` Maven places the script in target folder.

This is my `persistence.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/library.backendDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I tried.

But I have this error : **Error parsing JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc/myapp]**.
I guess that's because I have this in my _hibernate.cfg.xml_ :
`<property name="connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/myapp</property>`

Comment: I think that you do not need the cfg.xml... is you project a JEE project?

Comment: Yes it is. The only way I find to bypass this error is to comment this property in my hibernate.cfg.xml.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try to set the datasource in your persistence.xml. Also, can you post your persistence.xml and hibernate.cfg.xml?

Comment: I don't have a persistence.xml. I managed to bypass **Error parsing JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc/myapp]** by commenting **connection.datasource** properties in my _hibernate.cfg.xml_. Instead I did this before building session factory : `configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.datasource", "java:comp/env/jdbc/myapp");` it works now, thanks.